# How to get prefix value from decimal values in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I want to get the value without decimal value.

Like
I have value `25.4456` in `[A2]` cell, and I want to get only `25` from `[A2]` to another cell `[B2]`.

After that I want to multiply `[B2]` (that should contain only `25`) with some value, like 
in cell `[C2]` `=B2*5`
and value in cell [C2] `125`, but it shows `127.228`.

**I need value should be only multiply with [B2] (`25`) and answer `125`**

Anybody can solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have only one value in A2 or multiple, better share some sample data!

Comment: INT function will help you: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INT-function-A6C4AF9E-356D-4369-AB6A-CB1FD9D343EF

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try to use the `INT` function:

In `B2`:

```
=INT(A2)
```

In `C2`:

```
=B2*5
```

Or just in one go:

```
=INT(A2)*5
```